# How to properly format an array?

Tags: php

This code is working correctly:

```
$message = json_encode(array('jsonrpc' => '2.0', 'id' => 1, 'method' => 'getExchangeAmount', 'params' => array(array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETH', 'amount' => '1'),array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETC', 'amount' => '1'))));
```

But I'm trying to change it to this and it's not working:

```
$exchange_pairs = file_get_contents('exchange_pairs.txt', true);
$message = json_encode(array('jsonrpc' => '2.0', 'id' => 1, 'method' => 'getExchangeAmount', 'params' => array($exchange_pairs)));
```

This is the content in the `exchange_pairs.txt` file:

```
array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETH', 'amount' => '1'),array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETC', 'amount' => '1')
```

It's not my choice, I have to get this data from the file.  I know it's inconvenient.

I'm guessing that this line isn't valid but don't understand why or what it needs to be changed to?

```
'params' => array($exchange_pairs)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you change an array to string?

Comment: did you stored array as string in db ?

Comment: what needs to be changed? just get that `$exchange_pairs` to be a proper array, not that array string type incantation that you have

Comment: Added in an explanation in the questions.  Technically I'm getting that data via `file_get_contents` and I can't touch the file in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more note on this:  If you simply *must* consume the data in the format you've illustrated above, it would be much safer to simply ignore the fact that the data "looks" like PHP code (as in, it is trying to define arrays for you), and simply treat this as a text-parsing operation.  If you parse your way through the values, it will keep you from having to use eval() - because it's incredibly dangerous to use eval() on text that you've consumed from some file outside your script.  Here is one way to do it purely as a text-parsing operation:

```
<?php
   declare(strict_types=1);
   $fileContents = "array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETH', 'amount' => '1'),array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETC', 'amount' => '1')";
   $paramsArray = [];
   $fileContents = str_replace("'", '', $fileContents);
   $fileContents = str_replace('array', '', $fileContents);
   $fileContents = str_replace(' ', '', $fileContents);
   $arrays = explode('),(', $fileContents);
   foreach ($arrays as $arrayIndex => $array) {
      $array = str_replace(')', '', $array);
      $array = str_replace('(', '', $array);
      $subArray = [];
      $keyValuePairs = explode(',', $array);
      foreach ($keyValuePairs as $keyValuePairIndex => $keyValuePair) {
         $keyAndValue = explode('=>', $keyValuePair);
         $subArray[$keyAndValue[0]] = $keyAndValue[1];
      }
      $paramsArray[] = $subArray;
   }
   var_dump($paramsArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using file_get_contents() to get the *text* contents of a *text* (.txt) file.  You can drop those contents into a variable, as you have done here (in this case, $exhange_pairs), but PHP will still only see that content as a string.  Not as a series of arrays.  to make matters worse, the text file you're consuming seems to have the "code" crammed into a CSV format.  But you can't simply split the values on "," because the rest of the file also contains commas.

What's happening is that PHP is reading your statement like this:

```
'params' => array("A STRING VALUE!")
```

First, keep in mind that this is a **horrible** way to try to get array values from another file.  If you simply want to grab the values from that **text** file and read them in as PHP **arrays**, you'll need to parse those string contents and/or *eval* those contents.  (Please don't do that - but the current setup you're describing makes that seem like it might be a necessary approach.)

The **correct** approach is to get the data in that file into a standard file format (JSON, CSV, whatever), so you can efficiently parse it into variables after you read the text file.  But if that's simply not an option, here is one (very ugly) way to make it work:

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    $fileContents = "array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETH', 'amount' => '1'),array('from' => 'BTC', 'to' => 'ETC', 'amount' => '1')";
    $paramsArray = [];
    $arrayPieces = explode('),', $fileContents);
    foreach ($arrayPieces as $index => $arrayString) {
        if ($index !== count($arrayPieces) - 1) {
            $arrayString .= ')';
        }
        $arrayString = '$paramsArray[] = ' . $arrayString . ';';
        eval($arrayString);
    }
    var_dump($paramsArray);
?>
```